# Copy CD / DVD contents into an iso file

Tags: 10.10, dvd, iso, cd

The title seems to be self explainatory. I just want a software to do that. I already have `Nero linux` but i dont think it is capable of doing it.

---

Trying out the command line method
[image]
I get an Input /Output error though the iso file seems to be fine
also adding `bs=1024` doesnt help much

Comment: You get the `Input/output error` due to DRM protection.

Comment: .... and nero linux -can- make ISOs: file -> Burn CD image

Comment: @Rinzwind will that prevent proper copying?

Comment: That's what DRM is intended for. You will probably run into trouble if you try to install from it.

Comment: Check `dmesg` for more detailed errors.  And if it is a copy protected video dvd then you will need a program to decrypt and unlock it.

Comment: @psusi its just a cd with some pdf files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you feel like going terminal you could try this:

```
dd if=/dev/dvd of=/myiso.iso bs=1024
```

There are other examples here:

http://digitalsanctum.com/2007/01/26/how-to-make-an-iso-image-using-dd/

Comment: the link tells i need to unmount the cd before using the command. unmounting it causes the cd to eject.

Comment: @Ashu, you don't need to unmount it first.

Comment: adding bs=1024  to the line described above , can speed things up. Since it will be reading the disk in larger chunks

Comment: @psusi thanks. the burning gets completed properly but i get an error. edited my question.

Comment: @tomodachi not much just a few millisecs see my question

Comment: As to the new additions to your question, is this disk copy protected? If not, it could possibly be permissions. Try the command with sudo dd if...

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Same input/output error.

Answer (score 1):

**dvd:rip** is a full featured DVD copy program  A front end for transcode and ffmpeg. It provides an easy to use but feature-rich Gtk+ GUI to control almost all aspects of the ripping and transcoding process.

**AcidRip** is an automated front end for MPlayer/Mencoder (ripping and encoding DVD tool using mplayer and mencoder) written in Perl, using Gtk2::Perl for a graphical interface. Makes encoding a DVD just one button click!

**K9copy** is a KDE DVD Backup tool. It allows the copy of a DVD9 to a DVD5. It is also known as a Linux DVD shrink. It supports the following features: The video stream is compressed to make the video fiton a 4.7GB recordable DVD. DVD Burning. Creation of ISO images.

**Brasero** is a good option and available in the software centre

Also **K3b** is the one I use also available in the software centre (its more Nero-like)

Comment: Brasero in 10.10 is buggy. it gets stuck at 99% .... il try the others later